# What exactly happens to Leon at the end of Venetica?

Tags: venetica

Ok, in this question I am obviously asking for *SPOILERS*, so be warned.

I recently finished playing Venetica, and I really enjoyed the game. However, it seemed to me that I messed up the final confrontation with the heroine's brother Leon in the Doge Palace. Once the fight started, I lost sight of him. When I had finished the guards, he wasn't in the room anymore, neither alive nor as body. Also, he is never mentioned again for the rest of the game.

So my questions are: What exactly happens to Leon at the end of Venetica? Are there even multiple outcomes? What are the player's possibilities to influence Leon's fate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no real answer. He is just disappearing without a trace. That is also said in a fan-driven german Wiki:

> Da er gegen Ende des Spiels spurlos verschwindet, bleibt am Schluss natürlich die Frage, was aus ihm geworden ist.
>
> (*The reason he disappeared without a trace leads to the question 'what happened to him?'*) [[second last paragraph here]](http://de.venetica-scarlett.wikia.com/wiki/Leon)

I hope that heled after all the years of doubt. You did nothing wrong. The game just wasn't telling you enough.

Comment: Thanks. Learning that this was actually intentionally (and not some obscure glitch) does help indeed. Maybe during development, Deck 13 left this as a possible hook for a sequel, although today I doubt that we will ever see one. However, it should be noted that (as far as I can tell) your source is not an "official german wiki", but just a fan-driven wikia space.

Comment: Yeah, my fault. Changed it to fan-driven.